# Showing ${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})\cong{\rm Hol}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})$ for $n>3$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quaternions, automorphism-group, holomorph

This is part of **Exercise 5.3.4** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Holomorph+quaternions), it is new to MSE.

The second part is here:

- [Automorphism group of the quaternion group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195932/104041)

For previous questions of mine on generalised quaternion groups, see here:

- [Find the upper central series of $Q_{2^n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4345985/104041)
- [Showing ${\rm Aut}(D_{2^n})\cong{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})$ for $n\ge 4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4346437/104041)

### The Details:

On page 37 of the book,

> Let $\lambda:G\to {\rm Sym}\, G$ and $\rho:G\to{\rm Sym}\, G$ be the left and right regular representations of a group $G$. Then $G^\lambda$ and $G^\rho$ are subgroups of ${\rm Sym}\, G$, as is ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Now $g^\lambda g^\rho$ maps $x$ to $g^{-1}xg$, so $g^\lambda g^\rho$ is just $g^\tau$, the inner automorphism induced by $g$. Consequently
>
> $$\langle G^\lambda, {\rm Aut}(G)\rangle =\langle G^\rho, {\rm Aut}(G)\rangle;$$
>
> this subgroup of ${\rm Sym}\, G$ is known as the *holomorph* of the group $G$,
>
> $${\rm Hol}\, G.$$

Elsewhere in the book, we have:

$$D_{2^n}\cong \langle r,s\mid r^{2^{n-1}}, s^2, srs=r^{-1}\rangle$$

is the dihedral group of order $2^n$ and

$$Q_{2^n}\cong\langle x,y\mid x^{2^{n-1}}, y^2=x^{2^{n-2}}, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\rangle$$

is the generalised quaternion group of order $2^n$ (defined for $n\ge 3$).

### The Question:

> Prove that ${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})\cong {\rm Hol}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})$ if $n>3$.

### Thoughts:

The answers to my previous question (linked to above) establish that

$${\rm Aut}(D_{2^n})\cong{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})$$

for $n>3$. It might help.

---

By definition, we have

$${\rm Hol}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})=\langle \Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}^\lambda, {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})\rangle.$$

Here $\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}^\lambda$ is the image of $\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}$ under $\lambda$, *i.e.*,

$$\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}^\lambda=\{ g^\lambda: x\mapsto g^{-1}x\mid g\in \Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}\}$$

and it is well-known that

$${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}})\cong U(2^{n-1}),$$

where $U(m)$ is the group of units modulo $m$. (See **Theorem 6.5** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.)

That's all I have there.

---

In [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/quaternion.html), we have

- ${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^4})\cong \langle a,b,c\mid a^8=b^2=c^2=1, bab=a^3, cac=a^5, bc=cb\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_8\rtimes\Bbb Z_2^2$.
- ${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^5})\cong\langle a,b,c\mid a^{16}=b^2=c^4=1, bab=a^{-1}, cac^{-1}=a^5, bc=cb\rangle\cong D_{32}\rtimes \Bbb Z_4$.
- $\lvert{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^6})\rvert=512$.
- $\lvert{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^7})\rvert=2,048$.

---

Please help :)

Comment: The previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346437/showing-rm-autd-2n-cong-rm-autq-2n-for-n-ge-4) basically describes all the automorphisms and gives you the solution to this question. Look at e.g. the automorphisms $\alpha(a,b)$ in the answer by Derek Holt. Calculate $\alpha(a,b) \circ \alpha(a',b')$. This is equal to $\alpha(a'',b'')$ for some $a''$ and $b''$, what are $a''$ and $b''$?

Comment: Yes I agree, it follows easily from my previous answer. The elements of the automorphism group with $a=1$ form a normal subgroup that is isomorphic to $C_{2^{n-1}}$, and the elements with $b=0$ form a complementary subgroup isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(C_{2^{n-1}})$.

Comment: @markvs I don't think it is possible to copyright exercise to such an extent. This site would not have much content if that were the case, I think :-)

Comment: Please let us use the meta thread for any further debate about copyright, etc.

Comment: [Here is the thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34456/104041) mentioned by @PedroTamaroff.